# Showing that a particular function is in $L^p(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $r>1$, for what values of $p\in [1,\infty]$ does $f(x):= \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{r}}}{1+|\ln(x)|}$ belong to $L^p(0,\infty)$?

So, since $f>0$ on $(0,\infty)$ we can reduce the question to "for which $p$ is $\int_0^\infty f(x)^p$ finite". It isn't too hard to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f^p(x)=0$ and so $f(x)^p$ is bounded on $(0,1]$ so we can reduce the question further to "for which $p$ is $\int_1^\infty f(x)^p$ finite"

If we take $p>r$, then the fact that $\frac{1}{1+|\ln(x)|}\leq 1$ gives us $f(x)^p=\frac{x^{-\frac{p}{r}}}{(1+|\ln(x)|)^p}\leq \frac{1}{x^{p/r}}$, and thus since $p>r$ we get $\int_1^\infty f(x)^p$ is a finite number. If $p\leq r$, then I have no idea how to proceed. I have a feeling it diverges, but of course a feeling is not enough. How can I finish this off?

Comment: $f$ is not bounded near $0$. $x^{-p/r}(1 + \lvert \ln x\rvert)^{-p} \to +\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $r>1$ and $p>1$.

- If we consider $$ I_1:=\int_0^2\frac{x^{-p/r}}{(1+|\ln x |)^p}\:dx, $$ the
  integrand, as $x \to 0^+$, satisfies $$ \frac{x^{-p/r}}{(1+|\ln x
     |)^p} \sim \frac{x^{-p/r}}{|\ln x|^p}, $$ the integral $I_1$ is then *divergent* if $p> r$ and it is *convergent* if $p=r$.
- If we consider $$ I_2:=\int_2^\infty\frac{x^{-p/r}}{(1+|\ln x |)^p}\:dx $$ the 
  integrand, as $x \to \infty$, satisfies $$ \frac{x^{-p/r}}{(1+|\ln x   
     |)^p} \sim \frac{x^{-p/r}}{\ln^p x}, $$ the integral $I_2$ is then *convergent* *iff* $p\ge r$.

Since
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)^pdx= I_1+I_2
$$ one sees that the above integral is *divergent* if $p>r$, in that case: $ f \notin L^p(0,\infty)$, the integral is *convergent* if $p=r$, in that case: $ f \in L^p(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Where does $\frac{x^{-p/r}}{(1+|\ln{x}|)^p}\sim (1-x)^{-p/r}$ as $x\rightarrow 1^−$ come from? I can't see why the integral would blow up around 1 when it is continuous there.

Comment: @billybob I was correcting the typo. Thanks.

Comment: That's wrong. For $p = r$, we have $f(x)^r \sim x^{-1}\lvert \ln x\rvert^{-r}$ at $0$ and at $\infty$. Hence $f^r$ is integrable at both ends, and $f\in L^r((0,\infty))$. (cc @billybob)

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh my bad. I've edited my answer! Thank you very much for the feedback.